# Linq query pivot specific columns to row

Tags: c#, linq

I'm kinda new to linq.

But, let's say I have a table like this

| ID | Names | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30120 | John Doe | 12,5 |
| 30120 | John Doe | 15,75 |
| 30120 | John Doe | 10,52 |
| 30120 | John Doe | 10,23 |
| 30120 | John Doe | 13,89 |

and I want something like this

| ID | Name | Grade 1 | Grade 2 | Grade 3 | Grade 4 | Grade 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30120 | John Doe | 12,5 | 15,75 | 10,52 | 10,23 | 13,89 |

Would it be possible to fetch it using linq in C#?

Comment: Have you looked at Group By syntax yet? It would allow you to get a list of grades for each name.

Comment: sure, I will look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use groupBy, and  a simple manual mapping:

```
class Program
{
    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Grade { get; set; }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var courses = new List<Course>{
            new Course(){Id=30120,Name="John Doe",Grade=12},
            new Course(){Id=30120,Name="John Doe",Grade=13},
            new Course(){Id=30120,Name="John Doe",Grade=14},
            };

        var result = courses
                      .GroupBy(a => new { a.Id, a.Name })
                     .Select(m => Map(m));

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));

    }

    private static object Map(IGrouping<dynamic, Course> arg1)
    {
        var course = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        course.Add("Id", arg1.Key.Id);
        course.Add("Name", arg1.Key.Name);
        int index = 1;
        arg1.ToList().ForEach((p) =>
        {
            course.Add($"Grade{index++}", p.Grade);
        });

        return course;
    }
}
```

The only thing you need is to create a table from the dictionary.